# How to get current location of the User in Flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, service

I have followed the steps and examples mentioned in the flutter dev community, but I want to fetch location and get latitude and longitude separately. Also, can anyone help me how to use the values returned from async functions in dart?

> Here is my code which I feel is inappropriate.

```
Future<UserLocation> getLocation() async {
  bool _serviceEnabled;
  PermissionStatus _permissionGranted;
  LocationData _locationData;

  _serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();

  _permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
  if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
    _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
  } else {
    if (!_serviceEnabled) {
      _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
    } else {
      _locationData = await location.getLocation();
      return UserLocation(_locationData.latitude, _locationData.longitude);
    }
  }
  return UserLocation(15.25, 15.50);
}
```

Then while using it -

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    () async {
      location = await getLocation();
    };
    super.initState();
  }
```

The result I want is:

```
double latitude = location.latitude;
double longitude= location.longitude;
```

Comment: You shouldn't use async/await in initState, you should create a separate function and then use in initState or rather use FutureBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, you can define that in this way, let me know if it works

```
LocationData? currentLocation;


void getCurrentLocation() {
  
  Location location = Location()

    location.getLocation().then((location) {
    currentLocation = location
  })
}

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentLocation()
  }
```

Then on the widget side, add this check: You can get `latitude` and `longitude` values from `currentLocation` variable.

```
currentLocation == null ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : .....
```

**Plus:** If you want to get more information about how to build map application in Flutter, you can watch this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9hsWOCXb_o&t=78s&ab_channel=TheFlutterWay).